# Drupal User Relationship Query will fetch Count Common Friend

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

**Drupal User Relationship Query will fetch Count Common Friend**

*Problem with the query*

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT count(ur1.rid) AS COUNT
              FROM {user_relationships} ur1
              WHERE ur1.requester_id = :requester_id 
              AND (ur1.requestee_id 
              IN (SELECT ur2.requestee_id 
              FROM {user_relationships} ur2 
               WHERE ur2.requester_id = 1))
' , array(':requester_id',$requester_id, ':requestee_id' => $requestee_id))->fetchAll();

return $result;
```

please help

Comment: $result = db_query('SELECT count(ur1.rid $requestee_id AS COUNT
              FROM {user_relationships} ur1
              WHERE ur1.requester_id = :requester_id 
              AND (ur1.requestee_id 
              IN (SELECT ur2.requestee_id 
              FROM {user_relationships} ur2 
               WHERE ur2.requester_id = :requestee_id ))
' , array(':requester_id',$requester_id, ':requestee_id' => $requestee_id))->fetchAll();

return $result;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all. You have one param token in your query (:requester_id) and supply 2 bind variables.

Do you want to use requestee_id in your query? If so, you need to add a token for it in your query.